# How to simulate a hold click on a button class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i simulate a hold click down onto a button?
where i can use `elements.[0].click();` to simulate a click, how can I make it so that it would hold down the button for e.g 5 seconds instead of just letting it go?

sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button class="button" id="button">You released the mouse button.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("button").onmousedown = function() {mouseDown()};
document.getElementById("button").onmouseup = function() {mouseUp()};

function mouseDown() {
  document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "The mouse button is held down.";
}

function mouseUp() {
  document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "You released the mouse button.";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent to dispatch a mousedown event, wait 5 seconds, and dispatch a mouseup event.

Comment: With jQuery you could probably do the same thing with `trigger('mousedown')` and the same for mouseup

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that. Just visit http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ and search for `trigger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create events and of cause also `MouseEvents` yourself.

In modern browsers you can just do this by calling the constructor of the needed event type, ore by calling `document.createEvent('<EventName>')`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

You can then trigger this event on any element you like using `dispatchEvent()`
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);

function mouseDown() {
  document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "The mouse button is held down.";
}

function mouseUp() {
  document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "You released the mouse button.";
}


// bind click event on simulate button
document.querySelector('.simulate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('start');
  simulateMouseEvent(document.getElementById("button"), 'mousedown')
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('end');
    simulateMouseEvent(document.getElementById("button"), 'mouseup')
  }, 5000)
})

// capsulate the event trigger stuff
// see: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/
function simulateMouseEvent(el, eventName){
  let event;
  if (window.MouseEvent && typeof window.MouseEvent === 'function') {
    event = new MouseEvent(eventName);
  } else {
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    event.initMouseEvent(eventName);
  }

  el.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <p>
    <button class="button" id="button">You released the mouse button.</button>
  </p>

  <p>
    <button class="simulate">simulate</button>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```